# MySQL INSERT INTO (SELECT) with defined field

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to copy duplicate and insert data into a table like so...

```
ID, Value
1,1
1,2
1,3
```

Now what I want to do is an insert statement that will take all rows for ID '1' and insert it in again but with an ID of 2. The ID is not unique.

Is there a way to do this without looping through all rows and inserting one by one with a regular Select, then insert statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
insert into TABLENAME (id,value) select 2, Value from TABLENAME where id = 1
```

Comment: Is there a way you can do a Select ALL with the id of 2? Reason behind it that there will be multiple tables this will be applied to. Essentially copying from one "account" to another.